# How to enforce integral constraints for Neumann problem numerically?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am quite new to the field of numerical partial differential equation (PDE). In my understanding, to solve a PDE numerically, generally, is to transform the original PDE
$$ Lu = f \text{ in } U \tag{1} \label{eqn:pde} $$
into
$$ L_n u = f\text{ in } U, \tag{2} \label{eqn:npde} $$
where $U$ is a bounded domain in $ \mathbb{R}^n$, $ L $ and $ L_n $ are the differential operator and the corresponding numerical approximation respectively, $ f $ is a given function and $ u $ is unknown.
Furthermore, if $ L $ is linear, then by writing \eqref{eqn:npde} at different mesh points, one can actually set up a linear system
$$ A\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{f}, $$
where $ A $ is the corresponding matrix, $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are column vectors whose entries corresponds to the values (unknown and known respectively) at different mesh points.
The original problem is thus transformed into an algebraic problem to solve.

In solving \eqref{eqn:pde}, boundary conditions are usually supplied. For Neumann problem, the derivative of $ u $ at the boundary is specified via an equation. One can then follow the similar idea as above to transform that equation into an algebraic equation, and include that equation into the linear system above.
However, to ensure uniqueness of the solution to \eqref{eqn:pde}, one also needs to supply additional constraint occasionally.
This is sometimes provided in the form of an integral equality:
$$ \int_{\partial U} u \mathop{d}\! \sigma = c \text{ for some constant }c. \tag{3} \label{eqn:integral_constraint} $$
My main question would be

> How does one transform \eqref{eqn:integral_constraint} to include such constraint into the linear system?

To simplify our discussion, we shall assume $n = 2 $ and $ U = [-1,1]^2 $.
Assuming $ U $ is uniformly discretized with mesh size $ \Delta x = \Delta y = 1/100 $.
Then one can actually write the numerical approximation of \eqref{eqn:integral_constraint} as
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{199} u(x_k,-1) \cdot \frac{1}{100} + \sum_{k = 1}^{199} u(1,y_k) \cdot \frac{1}{100} - \sum_{k = 1}^{199} u(x_k,1) \cdot \frac{1}{100} - \sum_{k = 1}^{199} u(-1,y_k) \cdot \frac{1}{100} = c  \tag{4} \label{eqn:integral_constraint_n} $$
(Pardon me if I get the wrong sign in the above, or get some minor mistakes in the above equation, my main point is that we use different numerical approximations to the integral to rewrite the original equation)
In this sense, we can include \eqref{eqn:integral_constraint_n} into the linear system.
Is this what we should do?
The point where I can confused is that it seems like there will be an extra equation to the linear system, and hence the corresponding matrix will no longer be square, hence not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious way would be to approximate the integral by a quadrature on the mesh nodes.
$$
\int_{\partial U} u d \sigma \approx \sum_{k\in K} \omega_k u_k,
$$

where $K$ is the set of boundary nodes. This provides a linear equation.